# Excel Unique district ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so I'm working on a spreadsheet with cities and districts. I want to have a unique ID for every city. For example, if in the column D1 we have California, we should have let's say an ID of TEST-001, for New York, TEST-002 and so on. If in a next row of that column we have the same city name, let's say California again, we should again display TEST-001. Do you know how to do that?

- California (TEST-001)
- New York (TEST-002)
- Minnesota (Test-003)
- California (TEST-001)

I've tried `=CONCATENATE(LEFT(LEFT(M5472;25);2);"-";COUNTIF($M$2:M5472;M5472))` which creates a unique ID for every row.

Comment: What have you tried so far? As it stands, your question amounts to treating SO like a free coding service (which it isn't)

Comment: I've tried this command 
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(LEFT(M5472;25);2);"-";COUNTIF($M$2:M5472;M5472))
which just creates a unique ID for every new one so the final result from this function is California=test-001 New York=test-002 California=test-002 which is wrong, it just keeps on going from where it was left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few options depending on your version of Excel. If you have ms365 this will spill down:

```
="TEST-"&MATCH(A1:A4,UNIQUE(A1:A4),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Fact is that I use ";" as a separator and after I typed the exact same thing in the exact same "B1" column it didn't work showing me that the function is wrong, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: For the second one with the LET, it says "The first argument of  LET must be a valid name".  The first one just displays the error as it doesn't understand if this is a formula or not :(

Comment: @Coding_Harry, never mind these formulae. I overcomplicated the matter anyways.

Comment: Yep, the second one worked for me! You just saved my weekend :D Thanks mate, you have a great weekend.